# Running external script in rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

On a view in my rails app, I am trying to load an external js from Dwolla that looks like:

```
<script 
src="https://www.dwolla.com/scripts/button.min.js" class="dwolla_button" type="text/javascript"
data-key="key"
data-redirect="<% thanks_path %>"
data-label="Donate"
data-name="Test"
data-description="undefined"
data-amount="0"
data-guest-checkout="true"
data-type="freetype"
data-notes="<% @member.name %>"></script>
```

When I load the view with a link_to, the dwolla button will not load.  I have
to refresh the entire page for it to load.  What can I do to get this to load from a link_to?

Comment: Are you using turbolinks?